# Найти в большом массиве пары векторов, с косинусным расстоянием меньше определенного

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, оптимизация, vector

Есть набор из миллиона векторов в виде матрицы размерности `(1000000, 100)`, нужно найти те пары, где расстояние по косинусу меньше определенного порога, но если решать в лоб: считать расстояние между каждой парой, то на задачу уйдет порядка 70 дней, даже с задействованием всех потоков процессора. Есть ли какой-то более оптимальный способ?

Comment: Как у вас заданы векторы? Векторы случайно не разреженные? Вы указали метку `big-data` - вы работаете в кластере? Какой кластер?

Comment: @MaxU   , вектора представлены в numpy массиве

Comment: а какая размерность массива?

Comment: @MaxU ,1000000 векторов по 100 координат

Comment: координаты представлены целыми или вещественными числоами? Какой вывод у `print(arr.dtype)`?

Comment: @MaxU ,float32.

Comment: так вектора у вас разреженные или нет? много ли нулевых элементов?

Comment: @MaxU , нет,вектора не разреженные, но координаты от -1 до 1

Comment: Я посчитал расстояния для всех пар векторов для 10.000 векторов на моем ноутбуке за ~5.8 сек, используя `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(..., metric='cosine')`. Для 1.000.000 это займет в 10.000 раз дольше. Т.е. приблизительно 16 часов на простеньком ноутбуке. Главная проблема с памятью - все векторизированные методы работают со всей матрицей целиком. Для хранения вектора расстояний в вашем случае понадобится ~1.8 TB памяти - такие расчеты я бы делал на распределенном Spark кластере

Comment: @MaxU ,Спасибо,как раз собиралась в скором времени Spark или Cassandra осваивать

Answer (score 2):

Вдруг кому пригодится. Сейчас появилось множество библиотек, которые очень быстро (но немного приблизительно) считают разные виды расстояний, в том числе и косинусные, на довольно больших наборах данных. Например: `NMSLIB`, `Annoy`, `FAISS`.

Список актуальных библиотек (со ссылками) и тесты их производительности на разных датасетах можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks).

[image: бенчмарки]

Comment: полезная информация, спасибо!

Comment: @MaxU Да вообще удивительно, что библиотеки эти так то уже несколько лет как активно стали развиваться, а при этом довольно мало людей о них знают, я и сам тоже не так давно случайно наткнулся :)

Answer (score 0):

Смените алгоритм. Вам ведь нужно найти не все расстояния, а только те, которые малы. Насколько мал угол, между векторами которые вам нужны? Если порог по углу меньше 1.e-4  (радиан) могу предложить следующее:

1. Отнормируем все вектора на 1.
2. Для каждого вектора вектора ищем максимальный по модулю элемент. На основе номера элемента и его знака распределяем вектор в одну из 200 групп. Составляем список векторов для каждой группы.
3. Повторно пробегаем список векторов: Для каждого вектора ищем максимальный (по модулю) элемент X[max], а также элементы X[i], удовлетворяющие условию `|X[i]| > |X[max]| - α` где α - ваш порог отсечения по евклидовой норме (с учетом того, что вектора нормированы). Таким образом, при поиске близких векторов, можно проверить только те группы, которые соответствуют этим элементам (прошедшим порог).

Понятно, что можно группировать вектора бОльшее число групп (например по двум максимальным векторам), просто формула вычисления отсечения будет сложнее.