# Найти в базе наименьшее евклидово расстояние

Tags: python, mongodb, машинное-обучение, поисковые-системы

Возникла потребность искать самый удачный (подходящий) датасет сгенерированный нейронкой после распознавания лица.
Нужно выполнить поиск по базе и найти самого похожего человека.

У нас есть один массив:

```
[-0.14760402  0.18719167  0.04150053 -0.0921068  -0.16887078  0.02324709
 -0.04641612 -0.11630221  0.12370145 -0.07014455  0.24573359  0.03904079
 -0.27129778  0.02959204 -0.07295675  0.13609795 -0.13187698 -0.08968797
 -0.2012838  -0.16615982  0.0217059   0.00041627 -0.01858913  0.04955338
 -0.19024704 -0.18434721 -0.06982315 -0.05426939  0.15494351 -0.10451394
 -0.04299729 -0.07180098 -0.1690695  -0.08467829 -0.02749946 -0.00308757
 -0.01261706 -0.14929104  0.19307789 -0.05911519 -0.11811744 -0.00415748
  0.11933747  0.22268862  0.15321049 -0.04101308  0.12349229 -0.06126648
  0.09076166 -0.18876649  0.06199023  0.07674868  0.09749875  0.0716019
  0.12201017 -0.19290529 -0.01353829  0.21687341 -0.11010585  0.12630889
  0.04276971  0.00293659 -0.10534084 -0.08965943  0.12599346  0.09744062
 -0.07307861 -0.21842727  0.18325034 -0.15839542 -0.05597069  0.09004606
 -0.089193   -0.11996002 -0.3178705   0.05085036  0.38763958  0.19086862
 -0.14595589  0.02082828 -0.01978934 -0.07487711  0.05899249 -0.01674179
 -0.11979252 -0.02747795 -0.08680353  0.08834615  0.25229415  0.01445329
  0.00105722  0.23681179  0.08904405 -0.09763616  0.01047772  0.13714562
 -0.15587574 -0.02978589 -0.03372395  0.0463781   0.15200463 -0.13603318
  0.02152741  0.10868748 -0.1757534   0.06744438 -0.0318573   0.01892542
 -0.0262807   0.04844372 -0.15358914 -0.05309738  0.22137821 -0.20882189
  0.1269407   0.24391431 -0.02090507  0.02553483  0.11997325  0.03864738
  0.07777584  0.04860133 -0.09686276 -0.13455498  0.01073158 -0.15386821
  0.02141182  0.0842296 ]
```

Представляет собой набор чисел с плавающей запятой от -1 до 1

Мы его сохраняем в базу данных.

У нас накопилось таких массивов около 50.000

Генерируем ещё один массив:

```
[-0.18303205  0.07142412  0.01505323 -0.14673074 -0.17361142  0.02646742
 -0.03395279 -0.06831738  0.08645248 -0.07506754  0.22879875  0.00961941
 -0.21720028 -0.10564265  0.09235184  0.12250473 -0.09408396 -0.07704318
 -0.17983794 -0.10640886 -0.00760378  0.05881869  0.00609878  0.05506223
 -0.17767537 -0.30160218 -0.03009136  0.00688204 -0.02562195 -0.02175772
 -0.05757777  0.13162929 -0.16575503 -0.06576031  0.01825872  0.09892717
 -0.0990886  -0.04563086  0.16782466  0.00385343 -0.1655371   0.02370039
  0.06626146  0.26851994  0.25856623 -0.0427581   0.02065502 -0.03230648
  0.16015874 -0.30130655  0.06620336  0.1480027   0.08171275  0.02545679
  0.0743178  -0.09076802  0.00253361  0.18856071 -0.1644216  -0.03282868
 -0.00277766 -0.10307762 -0.12198099 -0.19316623  0.18896221  0.17105345
 -0.14985694 -0.1295868   0.08943356 -0.06235509 -0.10340865  0.04370517
 -0.19336724 -0.18820783 -0.37302011  0.09345791  0.33356905  0.1724074
 -0.21920988  0.01767435 -0.02863912 -0.01240025  0.08466867  0.0631162
 -0.08921493 -0.05865925 -0.02537591  0.08397133  0.18167101 -0.01622136
 -0.05787662  0.27105331  0.12237041  0.04605677  0.03525903  0.05793242
 -0.03242231 -0.06490842 -0.16594143  0.0506063   0.07158192 -0.08893429
  0.03126835  0.12600896 -0.18564469  0.23052448  0.03958503  0.06578501
  0.01276818 -0.08363014 -0.08138505 -0.0220259   0.09097432 -0.2337397
  0.10124329  0.1670257   0.05445097  0.14788289  0.12662688 -0.00762837
 -0.00578771  0.04282037 -0.15355538 -0.03583786  0.16012162 -0.03436102
  0.05533902  0.09013008]
```

Сходство этих массивов определяется через евклидово расстояние следующим образом:

```
dist = 1 - numpy.linalg.norm(a - b)
```

Где a и b это 2 массивы, приведенные выше (numpy.array).

И для них евклидово расстояние будет равно: `0.17664886547843417`

Или же другими словами, схожесть массивов на `17%`

Цель: найти среди базы таких массивов наибольший процент.

MongoDB позволяет сохранять массив и индексировать его в дальнейшем.

Через что и как лучше всего это реализовать? Может можно как то упростить?
Или есть другие, более удачные способы поиска по датасетам лиц (учитывая что они могут быть очень большие)?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, есть такие сервисы для поиска людей по VK например, я думаю они используют базу данных для сохранения подобных массивов и каким то магическим способом выполняют по ним поиск.

Comment: Запутался. В ищете ближайшую пару. Это должно быть проще.

Comment: Тк это поиск по лицам, мне нужно найти наиболее подходящий массив (следственно и человека) по базе через евклидово расстояние.

Comment: Есть вариант конечно перебирать, но он подходит только в том случае, если база маленькая. Как это сделать на базах со 100.000 лиц или 1.000.000 лиц я пока не знаю. Так же не ясно в какой базе данных это лучше хранить (от этого напрямую зависит как будет производиться поиск)

Comment: Уточняю задачу: в базе точки, база неизменна. Приходит новая точка, нужно определить какая точка из базы ближе всех к пришедшей. Так?

Comment: Ещё один вопрос: вы PCA к базе применяли?

Comment: База составляется один раз, содержит в себе массив, описанный в вопросе, и данные о том, кто на фото. Я пытался найти зависимость, чтобы упростить поиск. 

А что касаемо базы, её пока не существует как таковой, этот вопрос задал как раз для того, чтобы понять как её проектировать и где чтобы поиск был максимально эффективным.

Принимаю все советы по тому, что выбрать и в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: [Это](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) уже прочитали?

Comment: Прочитать, прочитал, осталось как-то реализовать в рамках MongoDB

Comment: Какой язык программирования?

Comment: Язык программирования - Python

Comment: [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) - хорошая стартовая точка.

Comment: Хорошо, погуглю, посмотрю, попробую, спасибо за советы. А то я имею выход с неронки, но не знаю как сделать поиск по куче таких параметров, для нахождения схожих лиц. Буду смотреть. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: [sklearn.neighbors.KDTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree) - самый популярный инструмент для поиска похожих.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас проблема в количестве данных/скорости их обработки, то я как-то уже [отвечал на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163269/260769)

Сейчас уже есть очень много библиотек, которые очень быстро (и с несущественным ущербом для точности) умеют считать несколько видов расстояний (включая евклидово и косинусное) для очень больших наборов данных.

Можно посмотреть [бенчмарки](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks), чтобы выбрать подходящую под вашу задачу библиотеку.

[image: sift-128-euclidean]