# Сравнение txt файлов с кодами, big data

Tags: python-3.x, list, scikit-learn, nlp

Есть корпус текстов, список списков.
Каждый список разной длины и включает коды типа 'y58u ufgh ko9u'.

Мне необходимо сравнить все txt файлы между собой по этим кодам, чтобы выяснить какие списки похожи на друг друга больше чем остальные.

Я пробовала брать CountVectorizer(), но объем данных несколько миллионов и памяти не хватает.
Порекомендуйте пожалуйста какие инструменты НЛП можно использовать для данной проблемы, с учетом большого размера данных.

При использовании OneHotEncoding и LabelEncoding возникает такая же проблема с памятью.

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема в том, что сам векторизатор потребляет много памяти, то можете использовать [HashingVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html), он *stateless*, то есть не хранит состояние, а поэтому практически не потребляет память. Кроме того, на выходе он даёт *разреженную матрицу*, которая тоже потребляет мало памяти (если её не превращать в обычную матрицу и пользоваться теми моделями, которые понимают разреженные матрицы).

Далее можно использовать разные современные библиотеки, быстро считающие расстояния, я о них писал, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163269/260769). Это в случае, если у вас много таких списков.

А если файлов/списков у вас немного, то есть и проще методы найти близкие пары, но, в общем дальше нужно от вас больше конкретики, что и как вы хотите делать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо, полезная информация. HashingVectorizer мне не подошел в связи с тем что обратной силы он не имеет и посмотреть какие именно токены имеют больший вес невозможно.

Comment: @Anna Тогда уточните задачу, приведите больше деталей. А то получается я вам отвечаю на поставленный вопрос - а у вас уже совсем другая проблема - интерпретируемость результата. Приведите больше деталей о ваших данных и проблеме, тогда можно будет дальше что-то советовать. Сейчас слишком много неизвестных параметров, от которых кардинально может меняться подходящее решение.